# How come I sometimes have options after hacking an enemy?

Tags: nier-automata

Sometimes, while hacking an enemy as 9S, a prompt comes up that allows me to choose what to do with the machine lifeform I've just hacked. Instead of simply detonating the enemy, I can choose to turn the enemy hostile to other machine lifeforms or I can control the enemy remotely.

Is it just chance that allows me to do this or am I doing something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While not explicitly mentioned, you will have more options available to you when hacking if you successfully hack an **unaware** enemy from behind.

As mentioned in the question, if you manage to pull this off, you are able to either directly control the machine lifeform you've hacked or simply turn them against their friends. It's also worth noting that if you choose to remotely control a machine lifeform, you can hack *another* machine lifeform and directly control *that* one, which means you can chain-hack your way through a group of enemies until you're in control of the one you want to control. This is especially useful if the machine lifeform you are controlling is near death -- you can simply switch to a healthier machine to keep on wreaking havoc.

Another important thing to note is that controlling a machine lifeform remotely is necessary for the trophy/achievement [Machines vs. Machines](https://www.truetrophies.com/t164869/machines-vs-machines-trophy), which requires you to kill 50 machine lifeforms while remotely controlling another machine lifeform.

Comment: Also worth noting that for the latest DLC there is an arena specifically made to fight machine vs machines (forest region). However, for fighting you can only choose from a set of machines you have remote controlled in advance at least once.

Comment: @NumLock interesting. I'm having to replay through the game so I can do the DLC currently, but I haven't seen that arena trial yet.

Comment: Just use chapter select and jump into a somewhat progressed state of the game, where you simply get to play any of the characters and get to run around in the world. The arena entrances (if you haven't found them before the DLC already) will be shown on the map as red markers. Like the investment bot between Pascal's village and the amusement park for example. The arena with machine vs. machines in the forst region for example can only be accessed with 9S.

Comment: @NumLock I meant that I don't have chapter select unlocked again yet. I made *that* decision after ending E.

Comment: I think it counts if you just remote control a machine and then cause it to self destruct (which may or may not destroy other nearby machines).  I got the trophy (as of last weekend, I got ALL the trophies, and not by buying them) and I didn't go out of my way to get it, nor did I really control machines and use them to attack.

Comment: @Andy I would assume it would only count those machines destroyed in the explosion. I earned this trophy a while ago, but upon replaying the game to access the DLC, I remembered how long it took me to figure out why I was given an option to control an enemy when it happened to me again.